# How to find and replace the first line word with vim

Tags: vim

I have a file like this:

> foo
>
> bar

And I'm trying to get something like:

> foo: foo,
>
> bar: bar,

I've tried `:%s/^\w/\0: \0,/g` where `^\w` matches the first word in line but I'm getting

> f: f,foo
>
> b: b,bar

Someone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `:set hlsearch` would have given you an indication that your pattern only matches the first word character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two characters (`\+`) which extend the match to the entire word, because `\w` only matches one character of a word and not the whole word.

The following should do what you want.

```
%s/^\w\+/\0: \0,/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing you could (globally) copy, paste and append:

```
:g/\v^.+$/normal! yEPa: ^[A,
```

(where `^[` is escape, entered as `<c-v><esc>`)

or use (lower-case) `e` if that is the kind of "word" you want